# Determine Transfer Function

Tags: transfer-function

I was given the circuit shown below and was told to find the transfer function H= Vo/Vi
[image]

However, while I was thinking over the circuit I noticed that since L C and R2 are parallel Vo is the same for all of the components. So couldn't I just perform voltage division over one component and R1 to determine Vo and then solve from there?

Comment: Do you think that you can just pick any one of the three for that purpose, at random, and ignore the others while getting identical results each time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a voltage divider circuit, but the two components of the voltage divider are R1 and the parallel combination of the other three parts.

Once you compute the parallel impedance, you can use that along with R1 in the voltage divider equation.

Answer (score 1):

To determine this transfer function, you can certainly use an impedance divider as recommended in some of the replies. However, if this technique will lead you to a good result, it may be a path for errors and mistakes while calculating the various products and paralleled results. Here we have a second-order system but add another energy-storing element and good luck.

In the end, you may end up with a complicated expression that needs further factoring before reaching a usable result. By usable, I mean an expression that you can use for designing your filter because this is ultimate goal of having a transfer function: being able to identify salient points (like a resonant frequency, a quality factor, a gain and so on) and deduct what should the components values be to meet these goals. Dr Middlebrook called it *Design-Oriented Analysis* or D-OA. You write equations to serve that purpose and this is what I can show here.

I will be using the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as described in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) on the subject. The principle consists of determining the time constants involving each of the energy-storing elements (two in this example) when the circuit is placed in different configurations. Intuitively, you see that for \$s=0\$ (the inductor is a short) or \$s\$ approaches infinity (the capacitor is a short) then the magnitude of the transfer function (TF) is zero: this looks like a bandpass filter and what is of interest is the gain at the peak.

Implementing the FACTs requires drawing multiple sketches that you solve by *inspection* meaning you don't write equations but visually *inspect* the circuit. Here you go:

[image]

Then, once you have the time constants in hand, you associate them as described in the below picture to form the transfer which, a few lines away, takes on the *low-entropy* format, nicely revealing the components we want:

[image]

In case you observe a deviation in phase or in magnitude between the *brute-force* expression and the *low-entropy* version, it is easy to go back to one of the sketches and fix the guilty one without restarting from scratch. Check out my 6th-order [exercise](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Divers/6th%20order.zip) here which illustrates the power of the FACTs.

Answer (score 0):

The impedance of the parallel components is:
$$Z_1=\frac{1}{sC+\frac{1}{s L}+\frac{1}{R_2}}$$

The ratio \$V_0/V_i\$ is given by \$Z_1/(Z_1 +R_1)\$:

which upon solving is:

$$\frac{s L R_2}{s^2 C L R_1 R_2 + sL (R_1 + R_2)+ R_1 R_2 }$$

Comment: Can always add a constructive comment, if you are downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

In the Laplace's domain:

Z2(s) = R2 // sL // (1/ sC)

Z1(s) = R1

Vo(s) = Z2 / (Z1 + Z2)

---

In the Fourier's domain, just substitute s with jω.

Calculations are identical to Laplace's domain.